# Reading MySQL indexes left to right, does the table col order count or just the index order?

Tags: mysql, indexing

When querying a table, it's the order of the index that counts, not the order of the actual columns in the table, right?

So if you have a 4 col table...

```
col1   |   col2   |   col3   |   col4
```

And make an index that is ordered...

```
col4, col2, col3
```

Then as long as your query is in the index's order, the index will be used, right...?

```
WHERE col4 = "blah" AND col2 = "blah" and col3 = "blah"
```

Cheers

Comment: it does not even matter, if your where clause is using all the columns of the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking what matters is the order of the columns in the index, not the table itself. However, the order you write the conditions in the `where` clause doesn't matter either. What matters is whether the engine can use one or more indexes to obtain the rows that match the conditions in the `where` clause. In your example, the index can be used but if you removed only col4 from the `where`, the index would not help even though the other columns are in the `where` and in the index.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The order of the `WHERE` clause makes absolutely no difference, as long as you don't have any `AND` vs. `OR` logic or parentheses or any other precedence constraint that forces it to be evaluated in a specific order.

Neither do the order of columns in the table make any difference.

The important thing is that indexes can only be used from left to right until a column is encountered that is not in the where clause at all.  When this happens, that column and subsequent columns of that index cannot be used for searching or sorting.

In your example, if col2 were not in the `WHERE` clause, then the index would be treated as if it only contained col4.  The col3 values in the index would be ignored along with the col2 values.